# Debug parameter in system.web part of the web.config file in my ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, debugging

I'm trying to find out some info on what does `debug` parameter do in this line of the web.config file for my web application:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true"/>
```

Can someone explain? And do I need to keep it in production product? For some reason that line stays in my web.config when I publish the web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It determines whether debug information is generated for the compiled assemblies. IIS compiles content automatically, so that if you alter a page file, your changes become effective automatically. the tag in question tells IIS how to compile it.

Comment: Thanks. So in a real world scenario what difference does that `debug=true` do to my web app? Does it make it slower, larger? Or what?

Comment: it may make it a touch slower, but we're talking about a very high level language so performance differences on that level are negligible. The real reason to turn debugging off when compiling for production is to not accidentally hand an attacker too much info on your site code, without at least making them work for it a little.

Comment: Why is it then set to `true` when I publish my web app?

Comment: Found this link about the debug parameter: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/prashant_upadhyay/archive/2011/07/15/pros-and-cons-of-using-debug-true-in-asp-net-applications-in-production-environment.aspx

Comment: very nice blog. If you are set to Release mode in visual studio, then i am surprised its set to true. if VS is set to debug mode, flip it an publish again.